# Jax-WS MTOM enabling issue

Tags: java, jax-ws, handler, mtom

I'm trying to write webservice using JAX-WS RI. This service contains attachment and annotated with

```
@MTOM
```

Also I wrote handler which checks ws-security usernameToken. When login/password are incorrect, handler generates fault and returns it to client. I'm trying to enable mtom on client-side:

```
((SOAPBinding)service).getBinding().setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

Finally I receive exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Missing Start Boundary, or boundary does not start on a new line
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeMultipartParser.getNextPart(MimeMultipartParser.java:148)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeMultipartParser.getRootPart(MimeMultipartParser.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:303)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeCodec.decode(MimeCodec.java:116)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:253)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:559)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:518)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:503)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:228)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:120)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:226)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:206)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:103)
        at $Proxy28.putContent(Unknown Source)
        at example.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Could anyone explain how to fix this?

**Update:**
Research shows that problem is on server-side:

response, i get from server also has "multipart/related" type containing boundry uuid
but in the message this uuid is null. 
Is there way to make response not multipart, or set up handler to work with it correct?

**Update:**
Finally found the solution(this is not optimal way, but for this moment this one works):
I don't know how to disable multipart in SoapHandler(javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler),   but SOAPMessageContext have a reference to HttpServletResponse, where you can write any data you have. Don't forget to close OutputStream, and return false in `handleMessage` method.
Also you need to set up correct CotnentType. This hack works for methods which send attachemtn to server, but don't have any in response(in my case there fault in response).

One again this is very "strange" way. But this one works.
If you have better one, please answer this topic.

Thanks

Comment: which application server ?

Comment: can you enable TCPMonitor and check the request your sending in and post it here?